# Unable to launch docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker which contains my existing postgreSQL database. Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.1"

services:

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    container_name: demo-postgres #you can change this
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

ANd when I type :

`docker-compose build`

everything is ok but when I type that :

`Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: is the container running?  did you try ```docker-compose up``` and then try to connect?  You can verify it's running by using the ```docker ps``` command

Comment: What are you typing exactly?  Are you running the client from another container, outside a container on the same host, somewhere else?